# Export multiples modules in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I need to export more than 1 module in my next.config.js file.

Now my file its like this:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = withImages({
    esModule: false,
});
```

And i need to put this:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
  },
}
```

And probably i will need to add more plugins

Comment: Why aren't you just adding `il8n: {}` as a new property on the original `exports` object?

Comment: like this? : ```module.exports = withImages({
    esModule: false,
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL'],
        defaultLocale: 'en-US',
      },}); ```

Comment: worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's to many ways to do this. I did this:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = withImages({
    esModule: false,
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en-US', 'pt-BR', 'pt-PT', 'es-ES'],
        defaultLocale: 'pt-BR',
      },
});
```

Worked fine